# "Nothing was sent to print..."?

Tags: windows-10, printing

I'm intermittently getting `Nothing was sent to print.  Open a document and print again.` on Windows 10.  I haven't been able to narrow it down to any specific set of circumstances.  Sometimes I can print things right away on the first try.  Other times I can get the error message a dozen times in a row before I'm able to get my printout to show up in the print dialog.  It always prints out on the printer fine if the print dialog loads properly.  It's like something goes wrong with the print dialog starting up.

It seems to have started doing this some time in the last 6 months or so.  I've had a couple of different printers (all USB attached laser printers of one type or another) on this machine in the past before the trouble started.  The current printer was fine at first.  What should I check?

Comment: Perhaps try reinstalling the latest software for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding more RAM to the system so it could process the jobs faster.  Appears something was timing out.